# Как установить python 3.7 на Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

На Ubuntu 20.04 LTS предустановлена версия python 3.8, но мне нужен python 3.7. Как мне его установить и выбрать именно этот интерпретатор python и как туда устанавливать модули.

Comment: лучше подымите в докере. Либо можно взять дистрибутив, которое позволяет такое из коробки (например, генту)

Comment: Ну например https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: "_Как туда устанавливать модули?_" — `python3.7 -m pip install module_name`

Comment: *выбрать именно этот интерпретатор python* — обращайтесь к нему по имени: `$ python3.7`. изменение цели у симлинка `/usr/bin/python` чревато проблемами с системными скриптами, которым может быть нужна конкретная версия интерпретатора. а вообще стоит освоить [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

`pyenv` позволяет паралельно установить несколько версий питона и переключаться между ними (системный питон также трактуется, как одна из доступных версий). Дополнительно, можно создавать virtualenv-ы базирующиеся на установленных версиях (и каждый такой virtuaenv выглядит, как отдельная версия).

Далее, `pyenv` позволяет указать конкретную версию (или virtualenv) для отдельной директории или сессии shell. Т.е. например, можно указать, глобально использовать одну версию, в папке проекта X - другую, а в конкретной сессии еще одну. Очень удобно и решает большинство проблем с разными версиями.

Вот пример переключения на `3.7.1` в текущей сессии и установка пакета:

```
pyenv shell 3.7.1
pip install some-package
```

Или создание `virtualenv` и установка пакета в него:

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.7.1 my-new-app  # создаем новый virtualenv с питоном 3.7.1
pyenv local my-new-app             # включаем этот virtualenv для текущей директории
                                   # при смене директории pyenv автоматически 
                                   # переключится на глобальный питон 
pip install some-package           # устанавливаем пакет
python                             # запускаем интерпретатор из virtualenv
```