# Как настроить virtual envirnoment для python 3.8 в ubunutu 20.04 lts?

Tags: python, ubuntu

Как настроить  virtual envirnoment для python 3.8 в ubunutu 20.04 lts?
Ни один способ из интернета не помог.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects/ML$ python3 -m venv env
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/ubuntu/Projects/ML/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

Comment: В тексте ошибки написано что требуется сделать. В чём проблема?

Comment: В том что это не работает !

Comment: Что конкретно означает "не работает"?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как установить python 3.7 на Ubuntu 20.04LTS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149987/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-python-3-7-%d0%bd%d0%b0-ubuntu-20-04lts) Там про 3.7, но решение годится абсолютно для любой версии питона.