# Как удалить старые версии Python (2.7-3.7) на MacOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Хотел спросить как можно удалить старые версии Python-a на MacOS

1. Через консоль через команду which нашел место где они хранятся но боюсь что могу повредить другие программы или же удалить не с корнями, заранее Спасибо!  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем их удалять? Просто используйте те версии, которые вам нужны, а те версии будут лежать в своих каталогах.

Answer (score 1):

В `/usr/local/bin` хранятся программы установленные с помощью `brew`. Удалить их можно также с помощью `brew`.

Сломать системное что-то не получится, так как в MacOS есть системный питон, который установлен отдельно. Сломать можно только те программы, которые используют не системный питон, в частности, установленные с помощью brew.

Я бы делал так:

1. настроил бы резервное копирование с помощью TimeMachine. Спасала меня миллион раз, можно очень просто откатить отдельные файлы, если что пойдет не так.
2. установил бы `pyenv` и в нем уже питон 2.7 и 3.х. Там они живут отдельно, можно удалять отдельно и т.д. смотрите детали, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149987/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-python-3-7-%d0%bd%d0%b0-ubuntu-20-04lts/1150062#1150062).
3. переключил бы в `pyenv` с системного или питона из `brew` на те, которые установлены на шаге 2
4. удалил бы питон(ы) из brew.