# Как понизить версию python3.8 на python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

При установке Ubuntu 20.04 установился python 3.8. Как мне понизить версию python 3.8 до python 3.5, так чтобы в системе ничего не "сломалось"? Или как удалить python 3.8 без вреда для системы и установить python 3.5?

Comment: Ни в коем случае нельзя удалять системный питон. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272831/lower-the-python3-version

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Как установить python 3.7 на Ubuntu 20.04LTS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149987/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-python-3-7-%d0%bd%d0%b0-ubuntu-20-04lts)