# Запуск скрипта на Python 3.x на операционной системе с Python 2.x?

Tags: python, linux, виртуальная-машина

У меня есть скрипт написанный на Python 3.x, можно ли как то его запустить в операционной системе на которой стоит интерпретатор 2.x, который нельзя обновлять. Может быть есть какие-то хитрости на подобии создания виртуальной машины внутри операционной системы или ещё что-нибудь?

Comment: [связанный вопрос ...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685123/211923)

Comment: может докер? если он там запуститься

Comment: Вообще смотря что за скрипт. Может с минимальными переделками и запустится на старом питоне

Comment: как вариант тянуть со скриптом окружение.

Comment: Этот способ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149987/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-python-3-7-%d0%bd%d0%b0-ubuntu-20-04lts/1150062#1150062 может помочь

Comment: а если не секрет, то что за система такая со вторым питоном в 21-м году и почему просто нельзя поставить третий? всё проще, чем создание «виртуальной машины»...