# Создание "полного" и независимого виртуального окружения (venv) в Python 3

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

Всем доброго времени суток!

Возник вопрос по организации независимого виртуального окружения (далее - ВО).

Что собственно это значит?!

Есть ряд машин с разными версиями Питона (например Linux c 3.5.$ и Linux c 3.9.$).

На последней машине ведётся разработка и создаётся ВО. При переносе ВО на первую машину и попытке его запуска система крашится.

И тут возникает вопрос: Как организовать изолированное, независимое ВО, чтобы оно работало на всех машинах "одинаково"?

Правка путей к требуемым целям не приводит.

Comment: докер контейнер?

Comment: Простите за глупый вопрос, а что мешает просто взять и заново установить ВО на каждой машине? ВО не предназначены для таскания по разным машинам.

Comment: Машины на которые будет ставиться приложение не имеют Докера (старая и закрытая версия Линукса).
Версии ПО на Линуксах, на которых будет запускаться Приложение старые и их не обновить из репозитория

Comment: Смотрите в сторону полной виртуализации - `qemu` и т.д.

Comment: Если на той версии ОС в принципе можно установить нужную версию питона, то используйте [pyenv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149987/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-python-3-7-%d0%bd%d0%b0-ubuntu-20-04lts/1150062#1150062)

Comment: К сожалению возможности установить более позднюю версию нет. На данный момент там стоит Python 3.5.2