# Создание виртуального окружения для проекта

Tags: python, django, flask

Имеется папка с веб сервисом написанном на python 3.9.1, а у меня стоит версии 3.9.5. Как создать виртуальное окружение для python 3.9.1, переключиться в созданное окружение и выйти из него потом. В данном проекте имеется папка venv c настройками. Используется ОС Windows 10

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как установить python 3.7 на Ubuntu 20.04LTS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149987/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-python-3-7-%d0%bd%d0%b0-ubuntu-20-04lts) Там вопрос про 3.7 и убунту, но решение кроссплатформенное и годится для любой версии питона.

Comment: Попробовал сделать как там, не получилось. В любом случае желательно через venv сделать, так как окружение проекта через него делалось

Comment: Вероятно вы не разобрались, как использовать pyenv. Вы не можете использовать готовое виртуальное окружение созданное одной версией питона с другой версией питона, равно как не можете использовать виртуальное окружение созданное на другом компьютере. Так что придется создать новое окружение. Далее, вам нужна еще одна версия питона локально. pyenv это простой способ ее установить. Вам необязательно потом создавать вирт. окружение с помощью pyenv, вы можете его использовать только, чтоб переключать версии питона, а окружение создавать вручную `python -m venv ...`

Comment: если у вас одна версия питона, а в оркужении нужна другая - то вам нужно поставить вторую версию питона и при создании вирт окружения испольховать нужный питон.