# Как обновить python на сервере на windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, windows

Необходимо установить django версии 4.1.3 на сервер, но проблема в том что на сервера по умолчанию версия питона 2.1.17 и максимальная версия django которую можно установить это 1.11.29, поэтому возникла необходимость установить новую версию python, однако я не понимаю как это сделать на windows.

Я решил проверить есть ли debian подобие, ввел python3 —version. Выдало 3.6.9, однако я не понимаю как через него установить django, при использовании pip3 install django==4.1.3 выдает что pip3 нету. Поэтому мне нужно либо установить напрямую версию новую версию python, либо разобраться как мне установить django через версию 3.6.9

Comment: Если debian-подобная система, то установите pip через `sudo apt install python3-pip`, потом устанавливайте то что вам нужно через pip3

Comment: Системный питон лучше не трогать. Пользуйтесь pyenv https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1150062/218971

Comment: А через что доступ получаешь к Windows серверу? SSH или через графический интерфейс Windows? В чем конкретно проблема скачать python? А для разных проектов лучше использовать виртуальные среды

Comment: Доступ через SSH

Answer (score 0):

Сначала установим необходимые компоненты для добавления пользовательских PPA:

`sudo apt install software-properties-common -y`

Теперь можем установить новую версию python 3.10:

`sudo apt install python3.10`

Проверим установленную версию:

`python3.10 --version`

Также проверим текущую версию по умолчанию:

`python3 -V`

Установим дополнительные модули стандартной библиотеки (venv):

`sudo apt install python3.10-venv -y`