# Не получается устанавить альтернативную (т.е. вторую в системе) версию Python из исходных кодов в линукс. В чём ошибка?

Tags: python, ubuntu, version

Устанавливаю в убунту 20.04 параллельно основной версии пайтона (3.8) более свежую (3.11-3.12). Действую по статье "Управление несколькими версиями Python под управлением Ubuntu 20.04", однако при переходе к make altinstall строка консоли забивается сообщениями типа
`gcc -pthread -c -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall    -fno-semantic-interposition -std=c11 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fvisibility=hidden -fprofile-generate -I./Include/internal  -I. -I./Include    -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Programs/_testembed.o ./Programs/_testembed.c` 
Компиляция завершается строкой

> WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

В чём причина такого поведения? Ещё месяц назад по этому же мануалу всё работало как часы, ставились две версии пайтона и можно было между ними переключаться...

Comment: А зачем, если есть [deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как установить python 3.7 на Ubuntu 20.04LTS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149987/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-python-3-7-%d0%bd%d0%b0-ubuntu-20-04lts)